# Interact between apps in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm developing two android applications let's call them app A and app B.
App A opens app B through and Share Intent and pass it params through a bundle, until this point it's ok, works.
Now, I want to realize some operations in app B and once these have finished close app B and return a message that operations has finished and the result of these operations to app A but I don't know how to solve it or how looking for.
I have thought another intent but it will reopen my app and delete the content of my screen that I have previously. Any suggestion?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ResultReceiver`:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html

Or `Messenger`:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html

I worked with `ResultReceiver` only, when developed SDK for one application. In first app you create an instance of `ResultReceiver`:

```
public ResultReceiver generateParcelableReceiver(ResultReceiver actualReceiver) {
    Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
    actualReceiver.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);
    parcel.setDataPosition(0);
    ResultReceiver receiverForSending = ResultReceiver.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);
    parcel.recycle();
    return receiverForSending;
}
```

and then pass it as an extra parameter to `Intent`:

```
requestLogin.putExtra("EXTRA_TARGET_RECEIVER", mAndroidUtils.generateParcelableReceiver(emptyReceiver));
```

Where `emptyReceiver` is:

```
    ResultReceiver emptyReceiver = new ResultReceiver(null) {
        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            //do nothing
        }
    };
```

As you can see, it receives `Bundle`. And in your second application, retrive the receiver, and pass the result when needed.

## NOTE

Please, make sure you use `android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver`, because there is another implementation of it(with different package name), and it doesn't work very well. This implementation contains in:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: I have implement a result receiver to handle messages.
In my first app create the class that handle on receive messages  and pass the receiver to the intent like this: sendIntent.putExtra("receiver",(Parcelable) resultReceiver); in second app get the receiver final ResultReceiver resultReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver"); but when I try to send messages to my app A I get the following error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver.send(int, android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please, don't cast your receiver to parceliable: `(Parcelable) resultReceiver`. Use code which I provided to you, i.e. function `generateParcelableReceiver`